# How do I calculate number of days with at least 6 consecutive days when the temperature >90th percentile in excel?

Tags: excel, temperature

I have daily temperature data of a place. I need to calculate the temperature indices. need help in calculating the number of days with at least 6 consecutive days when the temperature is >90th percentile. help me with composing the formula in excel. thanks in advance!

Comment: Show some example data both before and after. Preferably not an image so it is easy to copy and work with.

Comment: Date Id_6
01-01-2006 
02-01-2006 -19.51580645
03-01-2006 -19.51580645
04-01-2006 -14.97
05-01-2006 -13.08731343
06-01-2006 -13.09148148
07-01-2006 -6.363962264
08-01-2006 -9.141111111
09-01-2006 -1.81
10-01-2006 -25.47
11-01-2006 -10.75335079
12-01-2006 -7.572613065
13-01-2006 -5.198469323
14-01-2006 -2.824325581
15-01-2006 -4.444876581
16-01-2006 
17-01-2006 
18-01-2006 
19-01-2006 -10.92708058
20-01-2006 -12.54763158
21-01-2006 -13.45065041
22-01-2006 -12.61181946
23-01-2006 -11.77298851
24-01-2006 -16.75436019
25-01-2006 -9.767142857

Comment: It would be better to add the data appropriately to the question and not as a comment. You need to use the edit function.

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)